# Neo4j: results are duplicated

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, bolt

So I'm trying to find every Node that has at least a common Node with another one. This is the request I'm using to do this:

```
MATCH (source:Article)--(neighbor)--(target:Article)
WHERE NOT (source.unique_url) = (target.unique_url)
WITH DISTINCT [source.unique_url, target.unique_url] AS combo, 
     source, target, neighbor 
RETURN combo, 
       source.unique_url AS source_unique_url, 
       source.title AS source_title, 
       source.url AS source_url, 
       target.unique_url AS target_unique_url, target._id AS target_id,
       target.title AS target_title,  
       count(neighbor) AS common_neighbors
ORDER BY common_neighbors DESCENDING
```

But sadly `[source.unique_url, target.unique_url]` is always duplicated, like for one Node having a common neighbour with another one, I always get results like this:

```
[url1, url2]
[url2, url1]
[url1, url2]
[url2, url1]
```

I checked and the data is not duplicated in the DB, so the request is duplicating them, anyone knows what might be causing this ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: I think you need to give an example of input data on which to verify your query.

Comment: @stdob-- How can I do this easily ? Like an export of the DB or a plain text example

Comment: Since your MATCH pattern is symmetric, you're going to get at least 2 rows per matching pair, just with the places switched for `source` and `target`. While an inequality on the ids of the nodes should fix that (`WHERE id(source) < id(target)` replacing your second line), your return isn't symmetric. Is there any reason why you're returning `target_id` but not the id of the source?

Comment: @InverseFalcon not really, I could return whatever I want, the id is more for debugging purposes. I tried replacing line two as you said, and now I have: `[url1, url2]
[url1, url2]`
which is better, but still not perfect

Comment: You may want to double check that you don't have duplicate nodes with the same `unique_url` property in your db. Try creating a unique constraint on `:Article(unique_url)` and see if it completes without error. If not, the property isn't unique and you probably have some cleanup to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the start of your query like this.

1. Add direction to relationships
2. Add id(source) > id(target)

> ```
> MATCH (source:Article)-->(neighbor<)--(target:Article)
> WHERE id(source) > id(target)
> WITH ...
> ```